# djagno NotImplementedError: Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser

Tags: django, django-users

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.db import transaction
from .models import User
from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, CheckPasswordForm
from .decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST




@require_POST
def profile_delete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.user.delete()
        return redirect('users:login')
    return render(request, 'users/delete.html')
```

users view

```
    raise NotImplementedError("Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser.")
NotImplementedError: Django doesn't provide a DB representation for AnonymousUser.
```

I'm trying to delete user information in django, but I get an error like the title. What should I do?
I have also tried the @login_require method and middle_classes in settings, but the error is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

@qwe qwe - I dont think the request.user is a valid user. The error says Anonymous User which happens if the request.user is not logged in. You should also always add the @login_required decorater. That will ensure that you need to always logged in to access this endpoint.